# How to seriously troubleshoot extremely slow network printing?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, printing, printer

I have a printer (Brother MFC-L8850CDW) which is rated at 33 ppm (pages per minute), but I have only been able to get about 4 ppm (painfully slow.. one page about every 15 seconds).

This is consistent across a variety of printing clients (3 different laptops and 1 desktop computer) and has persisted over 2 Wi-Fi router upgrades. The Wi-Fi is very fast when communicating computer-to-computer.

I've gone through all the obvious settings tweaks, driver upgrades.

I'm now getting serious about finding root cause on this. What are some professional-grade tools (hopefully free and open-source) that I can bring to bear in investigating this problem?

***UPDATES***

I installed the BR-Script driver (I was previously using the one that ships on the CDROM and can be downloaded from their site, the *Brother Generic Jpeg Type2 Driver*). Nice to see it has the famous 300dpi option mentioned in many forums. Unfortunately, printing speed is the same:

Benchmark print time using a random 5-sheet document (10 pages duplex) @ 300dpi is 1 min 20 seconds. Spool file size is 2MB.

For comparison, the time to Copy the same 5 sheets is 1:08 (of which ~36 seconds is scanning time, which runs in parallel with the printing preparations after about ~5 seconds), and the time to copy just the top sheet 5 times, is 1:05. All copying done in color, duplex.

It appears that my printing is not significantly slower than the copying, they are both slow at approx 4 duplex sheets (8 duplexed document pages) per minute.

In all tests, even with a "warm" machine, the first sheet does not come out of the machine until 30-35 seconds into the test.

Does this all seem normal to everyone? Am I the only person on this entire site who bought one of these printers?

Comment: Do you have the same problem when connected via wire?

Comment: It is indeed slow. First-page-out time should be 15 sec, not 30. Duplexing will affect this though: the 15 sec should be until the first side is printed (when it appears briefly at the output). And it should print multiple copies at 32 ppm, not 8 ppm. Are you printing on plain (80 gsm) paper?

Comment: yes, plain paper

Comment: Try resetting the printer to factory defaults, as shown here: http://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=hk&lang=en&prod=mfcl8850cdw_us_eu_as&faqid=faq00000105_033

Answer (score 3):

Quoted laser printer speeds only apply when printing *multiple copies of the same page*. The first copy can take far longer as the page has to be processed by both the PC and the printer. That processing time depends on many factors, including especially the amount of image data involved.

You can get an idea of the amount of processing involved if you look at the spool file, i.e. the file that is actually sent to the printer. That can be much larger than the actual document.

When printing multiple copies of a document, it should be sent to the printer only once; the printer stores the page image in memory for the subsequent copies. If the spool file for multiple copies is larger than for a single copy, something is wrong, and you need to either select the correct driver setting (e.g. disable collation), reinstall the driver from scratch, or use a different driver.

If using the PCL6 driver, keep the resolution setting low (e.g. 600 dpi) as PCL sends images at printer resolution. The BR-Script (PostScript) driver does not suffer from that. To keep image data as small as possible, do not use images with a resolution of more than 300 dpi *as printed*. Using 600 dpi images can increase the spool file by a factor of 4 and nobody will be able to see the difference.

**Here is one way to check the actual printing speed:**

Make 10 photocopies of a single page. Start timing from the moment the printer picks the first sheet from the paper tray. The 10 copies should be delivered at spec speed (about 20 sec at 32 ppm).

Comment: Any tips on how to force use of BR-Script driver?

Comment: Install it - it's a separate driver. What speed do photocopies run at?

Comment: please see updates in question.

Answer (score 0):

SUGGESTIONS FOR IMPROVING PRINT SPEED

If you feel your Brother machine's print speed is too slow, please try the following suggestions for the printer driver settings:

The highest resolution needs longer data processing, sending, and printing time. Try the other quality settings in the printer driver's BASIC tab.

Click COLOR SETTINGS in the printer driver's ADVANCED tab and uncheck Color Enhancement (True2Life®).

Turn the Borderless Printing feature off in the printer driver's BASIC tab. Borderless Printing is slower than normal printing.

Found this article here: http://support.brother.com/g/b/faqendbranchprintable.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc495cw_all&faqid=faq00002724_000&printable=true

Comment: This information is outdated and/or wrong for my printer model. The options mentioned don’t exist.

Answer (score 0):

If this is windows, give this a try and see if it makes a difference.

Load up your printer browser in the control panel.
I recommend deleting all your network printers and restarting your PC, it seems that windows holds on to some information until you restart.
Go back to the printer browser in control panel
Click “Add a Printer”.
Now select add local printer.
Create new port. (choose TCP/IP)
When it asks for Enter a port name use the IP Address of the printer. (give it a sec, it should detect the port to use.)
Follow the steps to install the printer driver again, if you have installed the printer before, windows should still retain that printer driver you used.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers I found helped me with my slow print speed on Brother MFC-J77DW but I found a solution.

I remembered it started printing slow after I had printed a photo from Windows 10’s Photos application. In the Printer Properties, there is an Advanced tab. There is a “Driver” field with a drop-down menu. It was set to “Brother Generic Jpeg Type2 Class Driver.” But there is an entry below it for “Brother MFC-J775DW Printer.”

I set it to “Brother MFC-J775DW Printer” and the speed went back to normal instead of super slow.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to upgrade printing speed

- Upgrade your printer ram  (there is optional ddr2 256mb sodimm slot on your machine)
- Turn off all unnecessary features  on admin page (you should just have ipp/ipps and network scanning enabled and or airprint for mac users. (You need  to add printer under windows using ipp , ie using the printer i want isnt listed option and type http://printerip:631 and select the brscript.inf as the driver)
- Turn off ipv6 if you aren't using  it on admin page
- Use static ip on printer  on ipv4 /ipv6 admin page and set the dhcp lease reservation on your router (ip/printer mac bind)
- Print single sided (double sided duplexing slows print speed to 14pages/minute)